# Need Wordpress Newsletter sign up with SMS integration

Tags: wordpress

I Need a Wordpress newsletter sign up with SMS integration.
Is there any plugin or way to add this functionality to Wordpress?

I want the admin to have functionality to send the newsletter by email as well as notifications to a phone via SMS.

Comment: This question is probably more suited for the WordPress Stack Exchange.  You can find it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will check with wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for my client I've used Gravity forms and a 3rd party SMS gateway.

Where the 3rd party with provide you with the piece of PHP code which needs to be inserted inside the 
function.php file along with the gravity forms hook and function.

If you need more details on the same.